# Creating a password for new user when their first action *won't* be changing it

Tags: authentication, password-policy

On occasion we want to create a user account for important users who we've been in touch with in advance.

When they then visit our site, the ideal UX scenario is that they complete a third party form (generated by HelloSign) first, and change their password second.

Is there a good way to do this? I looked at eg [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79755/adding-a-new-user-email-temp-password-vs-link-with-token) on sending an initial password via email, which is the solution that first occurred to me. The top-voted response recommends against the practice in favour of getting a log in/reset link, but as far as I understand, the point of doing it via token would be to prevent any other activity before the password has been changed. Is there any secure alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are one time password reset links safer than one time passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148862/why-are-one-time-password-reset-links-safer-than-one-time-passwords)

Comment: @SilverlightFox related, but not duplicate. Question is about accepting user input before changing passwords AND one-time password change links.

Comment: @Mindwin: [My answer there](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/148925/8340) covers both.

Comment: @SilverlightFox It does not answer if there is a secure alternative to get user to input data before changing the password, or prove that getting user data before changing passwords cannot be done securely. see thel3l answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend that you do the following:

Once you receive their submission, create their account and set up a *random* password for the password field. Then send them a password reset link that'll also double up as a email verification link. From there, log them in normally.

Comment: and since they won't be logging in using that random password, please by all means make it a very strong, very random, very long disposable password.

Comment: @Mindwin Agreed. Just a random hash to block them